# Talkback does not announce aria-required="true" on Chrome/WebView (Android 11)

Tags: android, webview, talkback

I have a required input as shown -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The input required attribute</h1>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required aria-required="true">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I am on Android 11. Talkback (Chrome / Webview) does not announce "Required". Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Android with TalkBack doesn't announce "required" (known issue)

Read more from Scott O'Hara about [Required Attribute Requirements](https://www.tpgi.com/required-attribute-requirements/)